# MS Excel 2007 VBA function error (Object variable or with block variable not set)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to pass a range reference to a vlookup formula using a function. Below is the vlookup formula with the **mytrim** function:

Selection.Formula = "=vlookup(D1, sheet1!A:" & **mytrim**(Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Address) & ",2,0)"

Here's the code of my **mytrim** function:

```
Public Function mytrim(str As String) As String
Dim x
Dim y
x = InStr(1, str, "$")
y = InStr(x + 1, str, "$")
mytrim = Left(Replace(str, "$", ""), y - x - 1)
End Function
```

At the execution of end function step error is thrown "Object Variable or with block variable not set"

I am trying to get the vlookup formula as "=vlookup(D1,sheet1!A:AE,2,0)". AE being the last column in sheet1 which might change.

Comment: works for me.  Which line is give the error?

Comment: End Function line is throwing error

Comment: Does the value of `mytrim` equal what you expected? Could you put a Watch on `x`, `y` and `mytrim` and confirm everything is evaluating as expected?

Comment: Yes mytrim is returning column name and i am able to get to the end function line with no errors. Error appears when i hit F8 at end function line.  : str : "$BE$1" : String    mytrim : "BE" : String

Comment: @user2537864 have you checked the value of `Selection`?  I think that is your problem.  I'm guessing it is `Nothing` or something else odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your function.  As [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774606/ms-excel-2007-vba-function-error-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set?noredirect=1#comment38444852_24774606) and [you have mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2537864/user2537864), your code runs just fine and generates the correct return value, but you get the error when trying to return from the method.

Your problem is `Selection` would appear to `Nothing`.  Since you are getting the error on `End Function`, it means you are running into the problem when you are trying to set the resulting value.

I can't figure out how `Selection` would not be set (I didn't think it was possible actually) but I managed to repliciate the behavior with:

```
Sub test()
Dim Rng As Range

    Rng.Formula = "=vlookup(D1, sheet1!A:" & _ 
                   mytrim(Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Address) & ",2,0)"    
End Sub
```

So you need to check how you are calling this function and make sure everything is defined correctly in the left side of the function call.

Comment: Found the problem. It is with the column index number. I thought it was not significant to question so just put that as `2`. I am using `mycell.column` for index number and `mycell` is nothing, which is causing the error. i never used function within a formula so was skeptical about it's functionality. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.